# Wordpress- toggler pushes other elements away on page

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I'm new over here and i'm a newbie in webdevelopment/wordpress.
First of all, sorry for my bad English.

My problem is:
I'm working on a Wordpress page, by using the editor.
There are some contents on the page, just a few Edge Suite compositions and some text.

The compositions are referrals to some Magento websites, which are hosted by us company.

Now i'm trying to make a toggling div behind or under one of the compositions, to show some information about the concerned hosting.

But when I put in the toggler, the whole pages will bugg like this: [click](http://staging.skyberate.nl/shared-hosting/magento-hosting/referenties/?preview=true&preview_id=662&preview_nonce=1a108e5bdc).

I've tried very much togglers, codes, css only but all the same problem.

Conclusion: I have a toggler on a Wordpress page with jquery  and it pushes other elements away.

Please help me!

Greetings,

Thomas

Oh and,

I'm using the plugin embedit pro to shortcode the html, and i'm using "insert javascript/css" to use my javascript and css on a single page. But i don't think that should be the problem.

Code:

CSS :

```
    <style>
    .layer1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 250px;
    }

    .heading {
    margin: 1px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color:#c30;
    }
    .content {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color:#fafafa;
    position:absolute;
    }
    p { padding: 5px 0; }


    </style>
```

Jquery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"                 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".content").hide();
    jQuery(".heading").click(function()
    {
    jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Html:

```
    <div id="container">
    <div class="layer1">
    <p class="heading">Meer info</p>
    <div class="content">Hier komt de informatie te staan over de desbetreffende                 hosting.</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question. That way we'll be able to assist you better.

Comment: Okay, I just added the code, sorry for the long waiting, i didn't knew  how to add the code on the right way:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed! It was because I was in the administrator mode of wordpress, when I was looking to the website on another browser without staying logged in, everything stays on the right place. So, if somebody have the same problem, look your website in another browser without logging in to your wordpress/my-admin.